# python to R pipe not working

Tags: python, r, pipe, stdout, stdin

I am trying to send data from Python to R using pipes on Windows 8 using stdin and stdout

```
#Python code
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')  
for a in range(5) :  
    sys.stderr.write("enter something :")  
    t=input()  
    tt= t + "\n"  
    print(tt)  

#R code:  
x <-0 
while (x <8) {  
    x <- x +1  
    Sys.sleep(8)  
    while(length(line <- readLines(con = stdin(), n=1)) > 0) {  
        fname <-paste("Hello",toString(x),".txt", sep="")  
        fileConn<-file(fname)  
        writeLines(c("Hello","World",line), fileConn)  
        close(fileConn)  
    }  

}
```

The R code is not seeing anything being sent to it in stdin

Comment: This line `sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')` is telling python to use a specific file instead of stdout. Get rid of it, and it should work

Comment: Have a look at the rPython R package for interfacing to Python from R and the rpy2 Python module for interfacing to R from Python.  See http://rpython.r-forge.r-project.org/ and http://rpy.sourceforge.net/ to learn more about and get them.